# Spring No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/FirstSpringMVCProject/welcome] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, annotations

I am New to Spring MVC. I tried creating a new Spring Web Application.I am getting the below error in my  eclipse console **No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/FirstSpringMVCProject/welcome] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'**. But when using without annotaion it is working fine. It is not working for with annotaion method. Here is my spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml 
file

[spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc22l.png)

[HelloController.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yG8cX.png)

Please find my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <display-name>FirstSpringMVCProject</display-name>


   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd>
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">




    <bean id="HandlerMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />

    <!-- Non-Annotation Based -->


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.gontuseries.hellocontroller.*" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

And my HelloController.java file is

```
package com.gontuseries.hellocontroller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public ModelAndView helloworld() {

        ModelAndView modelandview = new ModelAndView("HelloPage");
        modelandview.addObject("welcomeMessage",
                "Hi User, welcome to the first Spring MVC Application");
        System.out.println("ga");
        return modelandview;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your web.xml?

Comment: If you are new to Spring, skip the legacy systems and their complicated setup--use Spring Boot instead. You can generate a self-launching project with [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io), and there's a wizard for it in IntelliJ and STS.

Comment: Posting code samples as images is not a good idea.

Comment: @Marek I am sorry about that, This is my first question to be posted here. In future let me correct that. Thank you for that.

Comment: Looks like your controller is not available in spring container. Change your component scan to `<context:component-scan base-package="com.gontuseries.hellocontroller" />` and try.

Comment: Thank you sir. Now my controller action is called. I can see that with the Sytem.out.println statement that I have printed in that method. I have also printed the final Modelandview that is being Returned. It is exactly same as my jspfile name. But still I am getting resource not available error(404). Is there any reason behind that?

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is working fine now.

Answer (score -1):

you can use following code into your web.xml and URL will b somthing /projectname/api/welcome

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:ApplicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: I have now updated my my web.xml and java class here.Please some one correct me, what is wrong with this.